# Unity2D - uniform positioning of transforms with different sizes

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have a rectangle (sprite) and I need to place different game objects (sprites) inside that rectangle but so they are all "aligned" by their bottoms.

For the life of me, I cannot make it work in Unity.

Say that my box has a height of 5.

I want to place the different size objects so they are all "resting" at the 2.5 y axis inside the box.

Does anyone know how I can do that since transform.position measures from the center of the GameObject?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should provide more detail for what you want to achieve like a screenshot of what you try to achieve.

Comment: your rectangle is quad ?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the responses...
Basically I wanted to stack one object above another object.
The object below stays the same size, the object being stacked on top of it, could be of any size.
I found what I was doing wrong... I was using transform.position on the object below and the subtracting renderer.bounds.y.
I found out that I was using two different tools to measure so the result was inaccurate.
 I am now using renderer.center.y and subtracting rendered.bounds.y and that gives me the exact y position of the surface.
Thanks again for the responses!!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use transform.position, use [RectTransform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html) properites, as they take anchor points into account. In particular you need to set the [anchor position](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-anchors.html) for the sprite in the prebab / inspector and then use [RectTransform.anchoredPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html) to position it.